# Downloading automatic all necessary libraries in python

Tags: python, import, python-import

I did this code to test some imports:

```
import os
import psutil
import pygetwindow as window
from time import sleep
import win32api
import PySimpleGUI as pys
import pyautogui as py
from time import sleep
import webbrowser
import winsound
import importlib.util
from random import randint
from datetime import date
import locale

layout = [
    [pys.Text(f'Complete =)', size=(25, 0))],
]
jan = pys.Window('Test', layout=layout, finalize=True)
jan.read()
```

I make a executable using `freeze`, and sometime appears the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named:(lib)`always is a different lib, i tryed for each lib run `pip install (lib)` but isn't worked.
Does exist some way for check if some lib is installed and if isn't, download automatic the lib in code?

> Changed Code:

```
import sys
import subprocess

packages = []
file = open('requirements.txt', 'r')
for lines in file:
    packages.append(lines)
file.close()

for library in packages:
    try:
        import library
    except Exception as e:
        library= library.replace("\n", "")
        subprocess.check_call(
            [sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', library]
        )

import pygetwindow as window
import PySimpleGUI as pys
import pyautogui as py
import importlib.util
import psutil

layout = [
    [pys.Text(f'Complete =)', size=(25, 0))],
]
jan = pys.Window('Test', layout=layout, finalize=True)
jan.read()
```

> requirements.txt:

```
PySimpleGUI
psutil
pygetwindow
pyautogui
importlib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by making executable using `freeze`?

I think you are referring to `requirements.txt` file this is generated  using  doing `pip freeze> requirements.txt` on commandline and dont forget to remove unnecessary import.You can download all necessarry library using `pip install -r requirements.txt`

for checking lib and installing automatics

you check by using `import <packagename>`

```
import sys
import subprocess

try:
    import <packagename>
except Exception as e:
    subprocess.check_call(
        [sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '<packagename>'])
```

Hope its help and learn about virtual enviornment

Comment: I use ```cx_Freeze``` to make my executables, i know that exist ```PyInstaller``` but no works in my pc =(

Comment: I edited my post, you talking about like this?

Comment: Well now look like you had confused me with your  problem heading.

Comment: I'm confused too, but, my problem is done, thanks haha